# SQL Case Statement in Order By

Tags: sql

I am having the following queries, in which **TOTAL_AMOUNT** is **decimal** data type and **INVOICE_NO** is **varchar** data type.

First Query working correctly. but Second Query results in error as, `Error converting data type varchar to numeric.`.

if I convert the **TOTAL_AMOUNT** as **varchar**, it sorted like **nvarchar**. But i need to sort as **decimal**. Help me to get the correct solution.

1)

```
SELECT *
FROM TRN_INVOICE
ORDER BY CASE '1'
             WHEN '1' THEN TOTAL_AMOUNT
             WHEN '2' THEN INVOICE_NO
         END
```

2)

```
SELECT *
FROM TRN_INVOICE
ORDER BY CASE '2'
             WHEN '1' THEN TOTAL_AMOUNT
             WHEN '2' THEN INVOICE_NO
         END
```

Comment: answered loads of times on SO. please search!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort dynamically on different data types you need more than one `case` expression, one for each data type:

```
ORDER BY
  CASE @sort
    WHEN '1' THEN TOTAL_AMOUNT
  END,
  CASE @sort
    WHEN '2' THEN INVOICE_NO
  END
```

Answer (score -2):

Your query working perfectly for me and sorting based on columns u give.. If u can share the whole query I can try it out.

Else you can try like this

```
SELECT *
FROM TRN_INVOICE
ORDER BY CASE '2'
             WHEN '1' THEN TOTAL_AMOUNT
             WHEN '2' THEN CAST(INVOICE_NO as decimal)
         END
```